# Как сделать такую анимацию при загрузке?

Tags: html, css

https://labs.pepsico.com/
Как сделать такую анимацию при загрузке?
Как реализовать такое увеличение букв?

Comment: Это никак не HTML + CSS, тут нужно знать JS, чтобы такое сделать.

Comment: Ну я ещё бонусом знаю next.js и ts. Поэтому можете смело рассказать как это сделать на js))

Comment: Если бы Я знал, Я бы кинул решение, а так не знаю, так как JS ещё не знаю(((

Comment: @JZ_52, js тут разве только для того что бы прелоадер запустить на какой-нибудь onload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конкретно на приведённом сайте, просто вставлена svg. Но это слишком скучно, поэтому вот вариант на [mix-blend-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode)

```css
.loader {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
  
    /* для анимации текста */
    font-size: 15vh;
    transition-duration: .5s;
    animation: 3s infinite alternate slidein 1s;
  
    /* суть в этих свойствах */
    background: white;
    mix-blend-mode: lighten;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  0% {
    font-size: 15vh;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  70% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    font-size: 100vh;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.content {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/seed/pepsi/0")
}
```

```html
<div class="content"></div>


<div class="loader">
  some text
</div>
```